# SSL for SaaS application

Tags: haproxy, lets-encrypt, saas, haproxy-ingress

How can i use Lets encrypt cert manger with Ha-proxy loadbalancer?I need to implement custom domain feature service on my SaaS application.Everything working fine except the SSL. How can i implement?Using Haproxy as a Loadbalancer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution. The easier in my opinion. It uses Haproxy Community and Certbot client.

1. Install Certbot client on a separated server and develop a REST API to interact with the client. Here you will be able to integrate your application with Certbot to generate the certificates.
2. Create a directory on HAproxy server to store the certificates. Install NFS on the server and mount this directory on Certbot server. When generating certs with Certbot, deploy to this mount point.
3. Create a deployment script for Certbot so it reloads Haproxy service when a new cert is deployed.
4. Schedule a task on Certbot server so it runs a renewal process once a day.

If you don't like the Certbot client, you can develop a client yourself. I am developing one right now in Scala to integrate with my e-commerce platform, it's not that hard.

Comment: its working when i use test.com and www.test.com.But when i access www.test.com as www.example.com by adding CNAME, Getting SSL issue.In my haproxy have acl host_star hdr_end(host) -i .test.com. if i use CNAME,i need to add acl like acl host_star hdr_end(host) -i .example.com to verfify DNS when create ssl with letsencrypt.Each cnew custom domain,i need to update the acl on haproxy to create ssl.How can i solve it?

Comment: All domain names must be included in the certificate as subject alternative names.

Comment: Fagunde Can i create multiple ssl without configure multiple server name on haproxy?Otherwise i need to add each domain name on haproxy config file before create free ssl.

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question, but if you have multiple certificate files, you can put them in a single directory. Each cert file name must contain the domain name. Then you can configure haproxy to read the certs from that directory. If this is what you are looking for, please let me know, I can provide you a sample config file.

Comment: **bold**
frontend https-in:
  bind *:443 ssl crt-list /etc/ssl/private/crt-list.txt **bold**
like this i have done.
But facing issue when i create multiple ssl.For example if i create ssl on nginx.i need configure the same domain in virtualhost.SAme as in haproxy i need to configure the particular domain name on haproxy config.Otherwise ssl didnt create.How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

tried to define the steps. Reduced from a larger script , if you have an error please write here to fix this.

Prerequisites :

1. haproxy installed , for example here: ip is 200.200.200.200
2. domain dns aquiered and directed to haproxy , for example here: test.com
3. http is working , if this is working then the whole web chain is working
4. have letsencrypt installed and with account
5. possible to stop haproxy and have the site down

Steps:

1. clean up old folders in /etc/letsencrypt that are with test.com `rm -rf *test.com*`
2. stop haproxy
3. run command :

   `certbot certonly --standalone --preferred-challenges http --http-01-port 80 -d test.com`

   `certbot certonly --standalone --preferred-challenges http --http-01-port 80 -d www.test.com`
4. check if all ok

   `root@200.200.200.200:/etc/letsencrypt/renewal# cat www.test.com.conf`

should be:

> ```
> #renew_before_expiry = 30 days
> version = 0.22.2
> archive_dir = /etc/letsencrypt/archive/www.test.com
> cert = /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.test.com/cert.pem
> privkey = /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.test.com/privkey.pem
> chain = /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.test.com/chain.pem
> fullchain = /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.test.com/fullchain.pem
>
> # Options used in the renewal process
> [renewalparams]
> http01_port = 80
> installer = None
> pref_challs = http-01,
> account = YOUR_ACCOUNT
> authenticator = standalone
> ```

5. create the folders /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.test.com and etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com
6. create the link files to the archive files

> ```
> ln -s ../../archive/test.com/cert1.pem cert.pem
> ln -s ../../archive/test.com/chain1.pem chain.pem
> ln -s ../../archive/test.com/fullchain1.pem fullchain.pem
> ln -s ../../archive/test.com/privkey1.pem privatekey.pem
> ```

7. copy the certificate to haproxy
   `cat fullchain.pem privatekey.pem > /etc/haproxy/ssl/test.com-fullchain.pem`

the same for www

8. add in haproxy a ssl frontend

> ```
> frontend test_com_ssl
>   bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/ssl/ ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA
>
>   default_backend test_com
> ```

the backend can be the same as for http frontend

9. restart haproxy , check if the certificate is active

To Check to see the expiry date of the certificate:
Type

`openssl x509 -enddate -noout -in test.com-fullchain.pem`

TO DO:
Not covered how to renew the script ,hope to do this in the future

Comment: its working when i use test.com and **www.test.com**.But when i access **www.test.com** as **www.example.com** by adding CNAME, Getting SSL issue.In my haproxy have **acl host_star hdr_end(host) -i .test.com**.
if i use CNAME,i need to add acl like **acl host_star hdr_end(host) -i .example.com** to verfify DNS when create ssl with letsencrypt

Comment: ssl can work only with www.test.com , no chance with www.example.com . You need to run all the steps for www.example.com every site has his own certificate, there are really special certificates covering multiple sites but not from letsencrypt. Happy I helped. Please mark the answer as the response